# How to reset/remove added filters 'posts_join' and 'posts_orderby' after the loop is completed?

Tags: filters

I am sorting results appear on the category archive page using these filters: `posts_join` and  `posts_orderby`. There is a widget, which displays recent posts. I am using default recent posts widget of WordPress. But it's not showing any result. When I investigated I found that the applied filters are getting applied to this query. So, I tried remove the filters using the following code:

```
remove_filter('posts_join', 'my_filter_join');
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_filter_orderby');
```

But still it does not work.

I also tried to put the following code in the filter functions itself:

```
// Disable this filter for future queries!
remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
```

It does not work either.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What priority are you assigning to your filters with `add_filter()`?  If it's different than the default, then you need to use the same priority with `remove_filter()`.  So, for example, if you have `add_filter( 'posts_join', 'my_filter_join', 20 );`, you would need to have `remove_filter( 'posts_join', 'my_filter_join', 20 );` to remove it.

Comment: I am using default priority. For example, `add_filter('posts_join', 'my_filter_join');`.

Comment: In principle, what you are doing looks right. Post your code in context please, so we can see how it is actually being used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to achieve this,

1. use a custom query for your widget using [get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) function where the query attribute `suppress_filters` is set to false (the default).  This would ensure your filters are not fired for this query.
2. add better validation to your filter to figure what is the query on which to apply the filter and else return.  Use WP [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to test for the page you're on ([category archive page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-category-page)) as opposed to a [sidebar/widget query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67716/how-to-determine-if-a-filter-is-called-in-a-sidebar-widget-context).